# BarDataSet. Longitud de las barras

Tags: java, android

Tengo este grafico de barras y deseo que los números que están encima de cada barra sean mas grande y de otro color por ejemplo todos negros del mismo color, es decir, en este caso la longitud que marca cada barra.

Gracias.

```
 BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(ListGraficos, "Gráfica de Barra");
                                BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
                                // Creamos los colores
                                barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                                // Separacion y anchura entre barras
                                barData.setBarWidth(0.9f);                                    // borde de la barra
                                barDataSet.setBarBorderWidth(2);
                                // Cargar la Grafica
                                graficosBarra.setData(barData);
                                // Movimiento de las barras
                                graficosBarra.setFitBars(true);
                                graficosBarra.animateXY(2000, 2000);
                                graficosBarra.setScaleEnabled(false);
                                // Pone la Barra centrada
                                graficosBarra.setFitBars(true);

                                // Quitar descripcion abajo derecha
                                graficosBarra.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

                                graficosBarra.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(true); // Poner numeros izquierda
                                graficosBarra.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false); // Quitar numeros a la derecha
                                // quitar lineas horizontales
                                graficosBarra.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
                                graficosBarra.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

                                graficosBarra.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);// quitar lineas verticales
                                graficosBarra.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM); // Poner leyenda cada barra abajo
                                graficosBarra.getXAxis().setGranularity(1f);
                                graficosBarra.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true); // Quitar nombre de las barras abajo
                                graficosBarra.getLegend().setEnabled(true); // Quitar leyenda

                                graficosBarra.invalidate();// Refescar la Barra
```